# Is it possible to use program output as values for brace expansion?

Tags: linux, bash, brace-expansion

I'm a linux newbie. I would like to know if you can use a program's output (which is comma separated values) as the values that will be used for brace expansions.

I was mainly trying to do this with touch but started using echo to test different approaches with no luck. the base approach is

```
echo b/{$(find sourceFolder -type f -printf "%f,")}
```

I also tried cat but got the same results. The output of find is used as a single value to the braces not multiple comma separated values. I verified this with

```
echo b/{$(find sourceFolder -type f -printf "%f,"),otherValue}
```

with this I get 2 outputs b/(with the comma separated values list from find) and b/otherValue

I was able to create the files with touch in the current working folder I wanted to see if its possible to do that in another folder.

Comment: This is not possible in bash, in zsh, on the other hand, you can do such a thing: `echo {$(awk 'BEGIN{print 1}')..3}` returns `1 2 3`

Answer (score 3):

It is frustrating but brace expansion is performed **before** variable expansion.  Consequently, you need a different approach.  Consider:

```
find sourceFolder -type f -printf "b/%f\n"
```

This puts `b/` in front of each found file name and does not require brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot do this directly with bash, you can use `eval` to obtain the same result:

```
$ eval "echo {$(echo 2,3),4}"
2 3 4
```

Comment: @chepner, valid point. Added it as comment, changed my answer.